# Sprite Kit Button touch location error | Swift

Tags: swift, button, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I'm trying to make a button that's an `SKLabelNode`. When it gets pressed, it's supposed to change scenes, but there is something wrong with the line where location is declared.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

    let location = touches.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

    if touchedNode.name == "startGameButton" {
        let transition = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Down, duration: 1.0)

        let scene = GameScene(size: self.scene.size)
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill

        self.scene.view.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
    }
}
```

The error is here on the line.

```
let location = touches.locationInNode(self)
```

It reads

> 'Set< NSObject>' does not have a member named 'locationInNode'

I'm not sure how to fix it. I've looked at a lot of working button templates, but mine always has an error.

Comment: Google "Set< NSObject>' does not have a member named 'locationInNode"

Comment: You can also try this Sprite kit button, it works like a native UIButton from UIKit

https://github.com/rogermolas/RMSpriteButton/blob/master/RMSpriteButton/RMSpriteButton.swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the error states - `Set<NSObject>` doesn't have a method named `locationInNode`. What you need to do is retrieve an object out of the `Set`; check it's a `UITouch` object; if it is, you can use it to get a touch location. Try:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if let location = (touches.first as? UITouch)?.locationInNode(self) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or

```
if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, this is the default fix, it just enumerates through all the touches.

```
for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        //do something
}
```